# Access denied when using runas on Windows Server 2022

Tags: windows, cmd, runas

This is something I encountered after upgrading our servers from 2016/2019 to 2022:

When I tried to open our Active Directory with another user, it would always deny the access even though the user has full admin rights.

I do not know what exactly they changed or why it is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I do not have access to the Group Policy (outsourced IT), I had to do the following for every server:

1. Stop the `seclogon` service (if running) over the console with `net stop seclogon`
2. You need to open the console with admin rights for this to work.  Paste the following wrapped command into the console and press enter:

```
sc sdset seclogon D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWRPDTLOCRRC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCSWDTLOCRRC;;;SU)(A;;CCLCSWRPDTLOCRRC;;;AU)S:(AU;FA;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;WD)
```

The `runas` command will now work again.